# Outputcache in MVC4 Application

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, caching, outputcache

I'm trying to implement a caching for some views and files on my MVC4 page (would like to chache on server and client). Looks easy but i dont get it why it doesnt work for me. I've tried this little example down here:

```
[OutputCache(Duration = 30000)]
public string Test()
{
  return DateTime.Now.ToLongTimeString();
}
```

Unfortunately the time of the result changes every second.. are there any settings in the webconfig or iis that must have been set? I didnt found anything about that but have no idea why even this little example doesnt work. Hope you can help me?

thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This should be working:

```
[OutputCache(Duration = 30000, Location = OutputCacheLocation.ServerAndClient,  VaryByParam="none")]
public string Test()
{
  return DateTime.Now.ToLongTimeString();
}
```

Comment: I tried this very simple example but still i get after every refresh (Ctrl+R) a new time?

Comment: take a look on this question, maybe you have a similar issue: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20027813/why-is-output-caching-not-working-for-my-asp-net-mvc-4-app

Comment: thanks alex. There was a global filter which automatic set a cookie - that was my problem.

Answer (score 0):

There wasn't enough information to decide either way, but it could be do to with parameters, you could try `[OutputCache(Duration = 3600, VaryByParam = "none")]`

or create a caching section and refeer to it by id

```
<caching>
<outputCacheSettings>
    <outputCacheProfiles>
        <add name="CacheExample" duration="3600" varyByParam="none"/>
    </outputCacheProfiles>
</outputCacheSettings>
</caching>
```

and then use

```
[OutputCache(CacheProfile="CacheExample")]
public string Test()
{
  return DateTime.Now.ToLongTimeString();
}
```