# OutputCache doesn't work

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, caching

I want to cache return data from an action. I use the `OutPutCacheAttribute` for this purpose. Here is my client code:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $.get('@Url.Action("GetMenu", "Home")', null, 
        function(data) {
            parseMenu(data);                  
    });
}
```

And here is my server code:

```
[HttpGet]
[OutputCache(Duration = 86400, Location = OutputCacheLocation.Server)] 
public ContentResult GetMenu()
{
    string jsonText = GetData(); //some code
    return new ContentResult
    {
        Content = jsonText,
        ContentType = "text/json"
    };
}
```

As you can see I use `OutputCacheAttribute` for caching server response. But it does not work. Every time I load the page the action `Home/GetMenu` is called. And it is called even if I type in browser's address bar directly 'localhost/Home/GetMenu'. Where am I was mistaken?

**UPD** I created the second action to test this attribute without debugging. Here is its code:

```
[HttpGet]
[OutputCache(Duration = 86400, Location = OutputCacheLocation.ServerAndClient, VaryByParam = "none")]
public JsonResult GetJson()
{
    return Json(new 
    { 
        random = new Random().Next(100)
    }, 
    JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
}
```

I supposed if OutputCache attribute works properly (and I use it properly) then action is called once and I get the same response every time. But if not then I get the different responses every time because every time random number is genereted. 
And when I called this action some times I have always received different respnses, such as `{"random":36}`, `{"random":84}` and so on

Comment: Have you solved this @Pupkin? I would like to know what the reason was.

Comment: @TorbjörnHansson sad but I haven't solved this problem

Comment: May be your output has cookie https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20027813/why-is-output-caching-not-working-for-my-asp-net-mvc-4-app

Answer (score 1):

In its default implementation, output cache is process-bound and stored in-memory. As a result, if you do something like stop and start debugging, you've destroyed anything you previously cached. Actually, more accurately, you've killed the process and started a new process, and since the cache is process-bound it went away with the old process.

Comment: I think it is not real reason. I added the following line to my code: `jsonText = jsonText.Insert(2, string.Format("  \"param\": \"{0}\",", new Random().Next(100)));` And every time I call this action (without debugging)  I get different response. Therefore my action is performed every time and CacheOutputAttribute still does not work.

Answer (score 0):

Please try this

```
  [OutputCache(Duration = 86400, Location = OutputCacheLocation.ServerAndClient,VaryByParam = "none")]
```

If not working Please try :

```
        [HttpGet]
    [OutputCache(Duration = 86400, Location = OutputCacheLocation.ServerAndClient, VaryByParam = "none")]
    public JsonResult GetJson()
    {
        return Json(new{message = "Record created successfully!!!"},JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
    }
```

N.B. : more information about [Outputcache](http://www.c-sharpcorner.com/UploadFile/abhikumarvatsa/output-caching-in-mvc/)

Comment: The second way has no effect((

Answer (score 0):

Have you checked `web.config` that it isn't disabled?

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms228124(v=vs.100).aspx

```
<caching>
    <outputCache enableOutputCache="false">
    </outputCache>
</caching>
```

Comment: I just have checked it. Web.config does not have this tag. Then I added it and set flag `enableOutputCache` to true but it takes no effect